# Is there anyway to change style of one row alternatively in a loop

Tags: c#, html, tags

In my ascx file I use a Repeater to create rows for the table. So basically I just repeat one row and populate the data into that:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
<tr class = "DGItemStyle"  id="myresultsRow1" runat="server">
<td  style="padding:0.5em;" align="center"><%#Eval("compnSN1") %></td>  
 <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
</tr>
</Itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I need to change the style of the row every time, from:

```
 CssClass="DGItemStyle"
```

to

```
 CssClass="DGAlternatingItemStyle"
```

then again and again.

So what I tried is replace : class = "DGItemStyle" by : <%#Eval("compnStyle1")%> , and I also populate compnStyle1 by the string

```
CssClass="DGItemStyle" and CssClass="DGAlternatingItemStyle"
```

alternatively in my codebehind.
But looks like the tag doesn't accept this solution. It shows this error:

```
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

So how could I archive this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Repeater.AlternatingItemTemplate`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
             <tr class = "DGAlternatingItemStyle"  id="myresultsRow1" runat="server">
<td  style="padding:0.5em;" align="center"><%#Eval("compnSN1") %></td>  
 <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
</tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr class = "DGItemStyle"  id="myresultsRow1" runat="server">
<td  style="padding:0.5em;" align="center"><%#Eval("compnSN1") %></td>  
 <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
</tr>
</Itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.alternatingitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know it is used this way. can't imagine it is such simple solution! Thanks for great answer !

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.alternatingitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
   <tr>
       <td style="background-color:Aqua">
          <b><%# Container.DataItem %></b> 
       </td>
   </tr>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
       <td style="background-color:Silver"> 
          <%# Container.DataItem %> 
       </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```